# How to allow incoming connections to ServerSocket in Windows7?

Tags: windows-7, serversocket

I made a custom http server using java. It runs properly on XP machines and when I open connection to that server from a different machine using its IP address and port it used to work. But in windows 7 it is not working. When I see the firewall it shows several rules. It would be great if someone lets me know which rule I should enable to allow incoming connections.

Regards,
Lalith

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please go through http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Allow-a-program-to-communicate-through-Windows-Firewall